# Python - Como ler subdiretórios dentro de um diretório e criar as mesmas pastas em outro diretório, caso não exista?

Tags: python, diretório

Estou tentando criar um código Python que verifica subdiretórios em um diretório (DirA) e cria os mesmos subdiretórios em outro diretório (DirB), se esses subdiretorios nao existirem no DirB. Como posso fazer isso? Até agora só consigo verificar se existe um diretório e se não existe o programa cria um novo, mas não consigo fazer isso para vários subdiretórios. Anexei a estrutura de exemplo abaixo e tambem o codigo ate onde consegui, mas acho que não está correto e não faz isso para as outras subpastas automaticamente, só faz para uma e tenho que especificar o nome dela.
Alguém poderia me ajudar nesta questão? Obrigado.

```
 - Dir_A (1 - Check the subfolders inside this directory)
     Folder_a
     Folder_b
     Folder_c

 - Dir_B (2 - Check if they already exist in this directory
     (3 - If not exist, create the same name/subfolders of Dir_A
```

```
import os


# Check if directory exists, if not, create it
folder = 'sub1'


def check_folder(folder):
    DIR_ORIGIM = (r'D:\RootDirectory\DirA')
    DIR_DESTININY = (r'D:\RootDirectory\DirB')
    SUBFOLDER = os.path.join(DIR_ORIGIM, folder)
    SUBFOLDER_DESTINITY = os.path.join(DIR_DESTININY, folder)
    CHECK_FOLDER = os.path.isdir(SUBFOLDER_DESTINITY)

    # If folder doesn't exist, then create it.
    if not CHECK_FOLDER:
        os.makedirs(SUBFOLDER_DESTINITY)
        print("created folder : ", SUBFOLDER_DESTINITY)

    else:
        print(SUBFOLDER, "folder already exists.")


check_folder(folder)
```

[image: imagem]

Comment: Os subdiretorios em nível abaixo importam ou você só precisa replicar o primeiro nível?

Comment: So preciso do primeiro nivel como esta na figura.  Eu estou tentando mas ate agora sem sucesso.  Ou seja, preciso checar os subdiretorios do diretorio A e criar os mesmos no diretorio B senao existirem ainda, somente os primeiros subdiretorios do diretorio A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`os.scandir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir) retorna um iterador para todos os arquivos e diretórios de um determinado caminho. Você pode usar [`os.path.isdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.isdir) para filtrar apenas os diretórios.

```
import os

def copy_subdirs(origin, dest):
    origin_dirs = [entry.name for entry in os.scandir(origin) if os.path.isdir(entry)]

    for dir in origin_dirs:
        try:
            os.mkdir(os.path.join(dest, dir))
        except FileExistsError:
            pass

copy_subdirs(r"D:\RootDirectory\DirA", r"D:\RootDirectory\DirB")
```

Comment: Muito obrigado @sourcream.  Funcionou perfeito. So nao entendi pq logo depois que eu postei a pergunta neste site de: duvidas, perguntas e questoes, em seguida 2 pessoas deram -2 na minha pergunta. O site fala "@Daniel é um usuário novo. Seja gentil ao pedir esclarecimentos, comentar, e responder. Consulte nosso Código de Conduta". E se eu estou postando minha duvida significa que eu nao to sabendo fazer e estou com duvida, mas os "inteligentes" que votaram negativamente, em vez de ajudar, ou pelo menos votar negativo mas, responder a duvida, nao fizeram! Obrigado vc me ajudou e ainda explicou